# finding degree of nonhomogeous recurrence relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am trying to find the degree of following recurrence relation : $a_n= a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+7$

I thought that its degree must be $2$ but , the answer key does not say anything about its degree. So , my question is that can't we talk about the degree of nonhomogeous or non linear recurrence relation. In other words , do only linear homogeous recurrence relations have degree property ?

thanks..

Comment: It is a linear recureence of *order* $2$, rather than degree $2$. I think the confusion comes from the fact that the characteristic polynomial  has degree $2$.

Comment: [Recurrence relation on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#:~:text=this%20defines,form)  "A recurrence relation of order $k$ has the form $u_n=\varphi(n,u_{n-1},u_{n-2},\dots,u_{n-k})$ for $n\geq k$."  Note that this covers the case of non-linear and non-homogenous recurrence relations as well to answer your question.

Comment: @Bernard doesn't order mean degree ?

Comment: In general, no. For instance a second order differential equation is a differential equation involving derivatives of an unknown function $y$ up yo $y''$ (derivative of *order* $2$. In a formal power series, the order of a series is the degree of its initial term.